# How to place kernel_entry function beginning of the text section

Tags: c, linux

My Kernel text section starts at address 0x80100000 & kernel_entry function is at the address 0x80585f70. I want kernel_entry should place beginning of the text section at address 0x80100000.

Starting address of text section

```
$ head -n 10 ../../../System.map
80100000 A _text
80100400 T __kernel_entry
80100400 T _stext
```

Entry point address in initrd image

```
$ readelf -h vmlinuz-initrd
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x80585f70
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          63759852 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x50001001, noreorder, o32, mips32
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         2
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         25
  Section header string table index: 22
$
```

I tried to solve the problem using linux linker script(vmlinux.lds) by adding head.o module at the beginning of text section.

vmlinux.lds linux linker script

```
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x80100000;
 /* read-only */
 _text = .; /* Text and read-only data */
 .text : {
  . = ALIGN(8); head.o(.ref.text)
  . = ALIGN(8); *(.text.hot) *(.text) *(.ref.text) *(.devinit.text) *(.devexit.text) *(.cpuinit.text) *(.cpuexit.text) *(.text.unlikely)
  . = ALIGN(8); __sched_text_start = .; *(.sched.text) __sched_text_end = .;
  . = ALIGN(8); __lock_text_start = .; *(.spinlock.text) __lock_text_end = .;
  . = ALIGN(8); __kprobes_text_start = .; *(.kprobes.text) __kprobes_text_end = .;
```

---

kernel_entry function format .ref.text

```
$ objdump -t head.o

head.o:     file format elf32-little

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000 l    d  .ref.text      00000000 .ref.text
00000000 l    d  .cpuinit.text  00000000 .cpuinit.text
00000000 l    d  .reginfo       00000000 .reginfo
00000000 l    d  .pdr   00000000 .pdr
00000400 g     O .text  00000000 _stext
00000400 g     F .text  00000000 __kernel_entry
00000000 g     F .ref.text      000000c8 kernel_entry
```

But I am unable to change this due to vmlinux.lds automatically generated through vmlinux.lds.S file.

I tried to put the same line ". = ALIGN(8); head.o(.ref.text)"
from vmlinux.lds but head.o is not found while building the kernel.

Please help me how can I resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you insert a symbol into a section, then all subsequent symbols in the section are shifted. If some code relies on the assumption that there is a certain object located at `.text` + `hardcoded offset` then the code will be broken.

If you decided to do that anyway, then you need to be able to edit the `vmlinux.lds.S` file or at least patch the generated `vmlinux.lds` before the linking stage. The `vmlinux.lds.S` is essentially a linker script + a bunch of C macros, so the syntax is pretty similar.

The basic idea is to put the `kernel_entry()` to a separate section called `.kernel_entry` and add a record to the `vmlinux.lds.S` that puts `.kernel_entry` to the `.text` before all other sections. The separate section is needed to ensure there is only one symbol in the section.

How to do that:

1. Put the `kernel_entry()` function to its own section. You may do that in the source code with a GCC attribute like this:

   ```
   void kernel_entry() __attribute__((section(".kernel_entry")));
   {
       /* function body */
   }
   ```
2. Put the `.kernel_entry` section to beginning of the `.text` in `vmlinux.lds.S`.

   Each architecture has its own `vmlinux.lds.S`, so the exact contents of the file may be different, but in general, you may find a `.text` section defined in `vmlinux.lds.S` like this:

   ```
    .text : {
            TEXT_TEXT
            SCHED_TEXT
            LOCK_TEXT
            KPROBES_TEXT
            IRQENTRY_TEXT
            *(.text.*)
    } :text = 0
   ```

   The `TEXT_TEXT`, `SCHED_TEXT` and so on are actually C macros that expand to some linker script commands. You may use the regular syntax and add `*(.kernel_entry)` to the beginning of the section, like this:

   ```
    .text : {
            *(.kernel_entry)
            TEXT_TEXT
            SCHED_TEXT
            LOCK_TEXT
            KPROBES_TEXT
            IRQENTRY_TEXT
            *(.text.*)
    } :text = 0
   ```

That is it. The linker will put `.kernel_entry` (containing `kernel_entry()`) to the beginning of the `.text` which is seems to be what you want.

Good luck!